# Loading multiple files in r within different folders

Tags: r

How to load from multiple files from different folders in r and then do row bind.

For e.g. folders are named "week1", "week2", "week3" ... and they all are with in main folder "Year_2020".

With in each weekly folder "week1", week2",... there are 7 different folders corresponding to each day of week and they are named in YYYYMMDD format. So folder "week1" has 7 different folders name "20200101", "20200102",....."20200107". Each of these folder has a csv file name VIEW_YYYYMMDD.csv as shown below. But they don't have any date column.

Folder structure is as below

```
YEAR_2020        week1      20200101           view_20200101.csv    
                 week1      20200102           view_20200102.csv
                            --------           -----------------
                 week1      20200107           view_20200107.csv
                 week2      20200108           view_20200108.csv
                 ------     --------           -----------------
```

sample of a csv files

```
df <- data.frame(Emp_Id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
             time = c(5,2,80,3,3,1,90,80,5),
             A = c(111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333))

   Emp_Id time   
   1    5 111
   1    2 111
   1   80 111
   1    3 222
   2    3 222
   2    1 222
   2   90 333
   3   80 333
   3    5 333
```

My problem is I don't have any date column in csv files and want to add a date column first for each of this individual files having corresponding date and then load and row bind then in r?

Most of the solutions are asking to keep all files in single folder but I have 52 folders corresponding to 52 weeks of "YEAR_2020" folder and each folder having 7 folder each corresponding to each date of week. So there are 365 "view_yyyymmdd.csv" files

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

main_folder %>%
  list.files(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE) %>%
  map(read_csv) %>%
  setNames(., basename(.)) %>%
  imap(
    ~mutate(.x, date = ymd(str_extract(.y, "[0-9]+")))
  ) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

where `main_path` is path of the folder containing week folders.